# Android, WireMock: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: android, wiremock

Android Studio 2.3.1, Android 7.0

My buld.gradle

android {
     compileSdkVersion 23
     buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

```
 defaultConfig {
       minSdkVersion 15
       targetSdkVersion 23
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multiDexEnabled = true
    }
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.6'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.6'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:+"
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-android:2.7.21"
    androidTestCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.6"
    androidTestCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.6'
    //WireMock
    androidTestCompile("com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.6.0") {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
        exclude group: 'org.ow2.asm', module: 'asm'
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.5.0') {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
}
```

My instrumented test (in folder "androidTest")  with WireMock:

```
public class WireMockApplicationTestCase2 {

        @Rule
        public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

        private Context androidTestContext;
        private Context applicationContext;


        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            this.androidTestContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
            this.applicationContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();
            wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(8089);
            wireMockServer.start();
        }

        @Test
        public void testWiremockPlusOkHttp() throws IOException { 
            String serviceEndpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:" + 8089;   
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = // some code fot http client;
            String uri = "/hello-world";
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(serviceEndpoint + uri)
                    .build();

            Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();  
            String responseBodyStr = response.body().string();
            assertEquals("hello world", responseBodyStr);
        }
 }
```

But when I start this test (on Android 7.0) I get error:

```
$ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class com.mycompany.android.transport.WireMockApplicationTestCase2#testWiremockPlusOkHttp com.mycompany.android.dev.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder;
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.HttpClientFactory.createClient(HttpClientFactory.java:48)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.ProxyResponseRenderer.<init>(ProxyResponseRenderer.java:53)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockApp.buildStubRequestHandler(WireMockApp.java:124)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer.<init>(WireMockServer.java:71)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer.<init>(WireMockServer.java:108)
at com.mycompany.android.transport.WireMockApplicationTestCase2.setUp(WireMockApplicationTestCase2.java:46)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1932)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.mycompany.android.dev.test-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mycompany.android.dev-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mycompany.android.dev.test-2/lib/x86, /data/app/com.mycompany.android.dev-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solutions of problem:

1.If you use Android 5.0- (e.g. Android 4.3) then you **MUST** use Wiremock version **2.0.8-beta**

```
androidTestCompile 'com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.0.8-beta'
```

2.If you use Android 5.0+ you can you use any Wiremock version (e.g. 2.5.0)

```
androidTestCompile 'com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.6.0'
```

P.S. Maybe this is a Multidex issues.

Answer (score 0):

In your gradle file, you probably need to include the android version of apache httpclient:

`androidTestCompile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'`

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter$1
 at org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter.<clinit>(Filter.java:21)
 at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.<init>(TestRequestBuilder.java:83)

 Error in app com.myproject running instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.myproject.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}:

Comment: $ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class com.myproject.transport.WireMockApplicationTestCase2#testWiremockPlusOkHttp com.myproject.dev.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError'